# Returning Coins From a Vending Machine

Tags: c++

I am trying to make the vending machine output coins for the total amount of change, starting with quarters and going down to nickels when the machine runs out of each coin (it is randomly determined how many of each coin are in the machine initially). I think I have the bodies of everything set up correctly but am unsure of how to execute the math for this problem. Any help is greatly appreciated

```
machine_quarters = rand() % 10;
    machine_dimes = rand() % 10;
    machine_nickels = rand() % 10;

    cout << machine_quarters << endl;
    cout << machine_nickels << endl;
    cout << machine_dimes << endl;
    cout << "(1) Lifesavers: $1.00\n";
    cout << "(2) Juicy Fruit: $1.25\n";
    cout << "(3) Big Red: $1.50\n";
    cout << "(4) Lay's: $2.00\n";
    cout << "(5) Dorito's: $2.25\n";
    cout << "(6) Cheeto's: $2.75\n";
    cout << "(7) Snickers: $3.00\n";
    cout << "(8) Reese's: $3.25\n";
    cout << "(9) Kit-Kat: $3.50\n";
    cout << "\nInput Quarters: ";
    cin >> quarter_input;
    cout << "Input Dimes: ";
    cin >> dime_input;
    cout << "Input Nickels: ";
    cin >> nickel_input;

    quarter_total = quarter_input * quarter;
    dime_total = dime_input * dime;
    nickel_total = nickel_input * nickel;
    money_input = quarter_total + dime_total + nickel_total;

    quarter_change = quarter_input - machine_quarters;
    dime_change = dime_input - machine_dimes;
    nickel_change = nickel_input - machine_nickels;

    cout << "\nMake Selection: ";
    cin >> customerChoice;

        switch (customerChoice)
        {
        case 1:
            total_change = money_input - lifesavers;
            cout << "Your Change is: $" << total_change << endl;
            if (machine_quarters != 0 && machine_dimes != 0 && machine_dimes != 0)
            {

            }
            else if (machine_quarters == 0 && machine_dimes != 0 && machine_nickels != 0)
            {

            }
            else if (machine_quarters != 0 && machine_dimes == 0 && machine_nickels != 0)
            {

            }
            else if (machine_quarters != 0 && machine_dimes != 0 && machine_nickels == 0)
            {

            }
            else if (machine_quarters == 0 && machine_dimes == 0 && machine_nickels == 0)
            {
                cout << "Change Cannot Be Given...\n" << "Amount Returned: $" << money_input;
            }
            else if (total_change == 0)
            {
                break;
            }
            break;
```

I'm expecting an output that would say:
Your Change is: $X.XX
Quarters returned: X
Nickels returned: X
Dimes returned: X

Comment: Can you start with only returning nickels, and figure a way to calculate if you could instead emit a quarter, or a dime?

Comment: Suggestion: Make a function that does nothing but figure out the change from an amount of money provided,  an the cost of the product, and the numbers of coins available. You can test it by itself without the rest of the logic until you are satisfied with the results. This will make you life much easier

Comment: Another suggestion: Work the math out with pencil and paper. Take notes. These notes will become the basis of your design and your design will ultimately become your code.

Comment: There a lot of variables going on here. Please provide a small verifiable example. Showing input and the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

**Algorithm to Make Change**

In order to put the logic together, you have to come up with a strategy for selecting coins.  It makes sense to select coins one by one from each of your largest coin type until that type is exhausted and then proceed to the next coin type.

You could do this in a number of ways, but the simplest( and not the most efficient) is to just keep taking quarters until either you run out of quarters or you the change left to be made is less than the value of a quarter and then move down to dimes.

I store all values in cents, but return doubles when printing.  I try to add _cents for any variable or function that deals with cents to avoid confusions.

So, the basic logic is contained in the make_change_cents() function

```
bool make_change(const uint price_cents,
                 const uint proffered_cents,
                 uint &change_cents,
                 uint machine_quarters,
                 uint machine_dimes,
                 uint machine_nickels,
                 uint machine_pennies,
                 uint &quarters,
                 uint &dimes,
                 uint &nickels,
                 uint &pennies)
{
  quarters = dimes = nickels = pennies = 0;
  change_cents = proffered_cents - price_cents;
  uint remaining_to_be_returned = change_cents;
  while (remaining_to_be_returned >= QUARTER_VALUE && machine_quarters > 0) {
    remaining_to_be_returned -= QUARTER_VALUE; // subtract value of 1 quarter
    quarters++;                     // increment # to be returned
    machine_quarters--;               // decrement # remaining
  }
  while (remaining_to_be_returned >= DIME_VALUE && machine_dimes > 0) {
    remaining_to_be_returned -= DIME_VALUE; // subtract value of 1 quarter
    dimes++;                     // increment # to be returned
    machine_dimes--;               // decrement # remaining
  }
  while (remaining_to_be_returned >= NICKEL_VALUE && machine_nickels > 0) {
    remaining_to_be_returned -= NICKEL_VALUE; // subtract value of 1 quarter
    nickels++;                     // increment # to be returned
    machine_nickels--;               // decrement # remaining
  }
  while (remaining_to_be_returned >= PENNY_VALUE && PENNY_VALUE > 0) {
    remaining_to_be_returned -= PENNY_VALUE; // subtract value of 1 quarter
    pennies++;                     // increment # to be returned
    machine_pennies--;               // decrement # remaining
  }
  if (remaining_to_be_returned > 0) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }

}
```

You said that you were having trouble with the math.  This function provides a simple algorithm to handle the math.

You said that you already have the rest of the code written.  Even so, I went ahead and wrote up an implementation to make sure that my make_change_cents() function worked.  Here is my version of the rest of the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>

/// make_change()
/// price_cents -- in
/// proffered_cents -- in
/// machine_quarters,-- in
/// machine_dimes, -- in
/// machine_nickels-- in
/// machine_pennies-- in
/// quarters --out
/// dimes --out
/// nickels --out
/// pennies --out
/// returns false if not able to make change
/// returns true if able to make change.
const uint QUARTER_VALUE{25};

const uint DIME_VALUE{10};

const uint NICKEL_VALUE{5};

const uint PENNY_VALUE{1};

std::vector<std::tuple<uint, uint, std::string>> tuples
    {{1, 100, "Lifesavers"}, {2, 125, "Juicy Fruit"}, {3, 150, "Big Red"},
     {4, 200, "Lay's"}, {5, 225, "Dorito's"}, {6, 275, "Cheeto's"},
     {7, 300, "Snickers"}, {8, 325, "Reese's"}, {9, 350, "Kit-Kat"},};

bool make_change(const uint price_cents,
                 const uint proffered_cents,
                 uint &change_cents,
                 uint machine_quarters,
                 uint machine_dimes,
                 uint machine_nickels,
                 uint machine_pennies,
                 uint &quarters,
                 uint &dimes,
                 uint &nickels,
                 uint &pennies)
{
  quarters = dimes = nickels = pennies = 0;
  change_cents = proffered_cents - price_cents;
  uint remaining_to_be_returned = change_cents;
  while (remaining_to_be_returned >= QUARTER_VALUE && machine_quarters > 0) {
    remaining_to_be_returned -= QUARTER_VALUE; // subtract value of 1 quarter
    quarters++;                     // increment # to be returned
    machine_quarters--;               // decrement # remaining
  }
  while (remaining_to_be_returned >= DIME_VALUE && machine_dimes > 0) {
    remaining_to_be_returned -= DIME_VALUE; // subtract value of 1 quarter
    dimes++;                     // increment # to be returned
    machine_dimes--;               // decrement # remaining
  }
  while (remaining_to_be_returned >= NICKEL_VALUE && machine_nickels > 0) {
    remaining_to_be_returned -= NICKEL_VALUE; // subtract value of 1 quarter
    nickels++;                     // increment # to be returned
    machine_nickels--;               // decrement # remaining
  }
  while (remaining_to_be_returned >= PENNY_VALUE && PENNY_VALUE > 0) {
    remaining_to_be_returned -= PENNY_VALUE; // subtract value of 1 quarter
    pennies++;                     // increment # to be returned
    machine_pennies--;               // decrement # remaining
  }
  if (remaining_to_be_returned > 0) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }

}

void generate_machine_reserves(uint &machine_quarters,
                               uint &machine_dimes,
                               uint &machine_nickels,
                               uint &machine_pennies)
{
  /* initialize random seed: */
  srand(time(NULL));
  machine_quarters = rand() % 10;  // range is 0 - 9
  machine_dimes = rand() % 10;
  machine_nickels = rand() % 10;
}

void display_choices()
{
  int i = 1;
  for (const auto &element: tuples) {
    std::cout << "(" << std::get<0>(element) << ") " << std::get<2>(element)
              << std::fixed << ": $" << std::setprecision(2)
              << ((double) std::get<1>(element) / 100) << "\n";
  }
}

uint get_choice()
{
  uint choice = 0;
  std::string input_line;

  while (choice < 1 || choice > 9) {
    std::cout << "Please provide a choice between 1 and 9:\n\n";
    std::getline(std::cin, input_line);
    std::istringstream ss(input_line);
    ss >> choice;
  }
  return choice;
}

// Return submitted payment amount in cents
uint get_payment_amount_cents()
{
  std::string input_line;

  double parsed_double = -1;
  uint retval = 0;

  std::cout << "Please provide the payment amount you are submitting as\n"
               "a decimal number in dollars.  This machine cannot return\n"
               "dollar bills.  This machine only returns change in\n"
               "quarters, dimes, nickels, and pennies, as long as the\n"
               "total to be returned does not exceed the amount of change\n"
               "on hand. \n";

  while (parsed_double <= 0) {
    getline(std::cin, input_line);
    std::stringstream ss(input_line);
    ss >> parsed_double;
    if (parsed_double <= 0) {
      std::cout
          << "Please try again.  Your amount was not an acceptable number\n";
    }
  }

  return (uint) (parsed_double * 100);
}

int main()
{
  uint machine_quarters;
  uint machine_dimes;
  uint machine_nickels;
  uint machine_pennies;
  uint choice = 0;

  uint quarters;
  uint dimes;
  uint nickels;
  uint pennies;

  uint change_cents;

  generate_machine_reserves(machine_quarters,
                            machine_dimes,
                            machine_nickels,
                            machine_pennies);

  display_choices();
  choice = get_choice();

  change_cents = get_payment_amount_cents();

  std::cout << "machine_quarters: " << machine_quarters << std::endl;
  std::cout << "machine_dimes: " << machine_dimes << std::endl;
  std::cout << "machine_nickels: " << machine_nickels << std::endl;
  std::cout << "machine_pennies: " << machine_pennies << std::endl;

  if (make_change(std::get<1>(tuples[choice
                      - 1]),  // 1-based choices in 0-based vector
                  change_cents,
                  change_cents,
                  machine_quarters,
                  machine_dimes,
                  machine_nickels,
                  machine_pennies,
                  quarters,
                  dimes,
                  nickels,
                  pennies)) {
    std::cout << "Your Change is: $" << std::setprecision(2) << std::fixed
              << (double) change_cents / 100 <<

              std::endl;
    std::cout << "quarters: " << quarters << std::endl;
    std::cout << "dimes: " << dimes << std::endl;
    std::cout << "nickels: " << nickels << std::endl;
    std::cout << "pennies: " << pennies << std::endl;

  } else {
    std::cout << "Sorry, change cannot be given at this time.\n";
  }
}
```